# puppeteer page.$$(selector).length is 2 but page.$$(selector)[1] is undefined

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, puppeteer

I'm trying to run the following selector through puppeteer `page.$$(".paging:not(.ng-hide) button.paging-button")`
This returns <s>an empty array</s> what appears to be an array of two elementHandles but when I access `pagingButton[1]` I get `undefined`

<s>, but when I go to the page and run `document.querySelectorAll(".paging:not(.ng-hide) button.paging-button")` I get two elements (which is what I want) It's my understanding that puppeteer uses `document.querySelectorAll()` under the hood but I don't know why my selector is broken in puppeteer. Could it be my use of `:not()`? My query won't work without that selector since there's `n` amount of elements that match my selector without it but only 2 that don't have the `.ng-hide` class</s>

Here's my code

```js
async function advancePage(page)
{
    const pagingButton = await page.$$(PAGING_BUTTON)[1];
    console.log(pagingButton)
    let adHocs = await getCalcsOnPage(page);
    const isButtonDisabled = await page.evaluate(el=>el.disabled,pagingButton)
    if(isButtonDisabled)
    {return adHocs}
    else{
        console.log(chalk.bgBlue("ADVANCING PAGE"))
        await pagingButton.click();
        const nextPageCalcs = await advancePage()
        adHocs.concat(nextPageCalcs)
        return adHocs
    }
    
}
```

and I have my selectors declared in another file

```js
export const PAGING_BUTTON = ".paging:not(.ng-hide) button.paging-button"
```

this is what I get when I log the output of `await page.$$(PAGING_BUTTON)`

```
[
  ElementHandle {
    _disposed: false,
    _context: ExecutionContext {
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _world: [DOMWorld],
      _contextId: 3,
      _contextName: ''
    },
    _client: CDPSession {
      eventsMap: [Map],
      emitter: [Object],
      _callbacks: Map(0) {},
      _connection: [Connection],
      _targetType: 'page',
      _sessionId: '23E3541B1A29459485B04919F5C5C74A'
    },
    _remoteObject: {
      type: 'object',
      subtype: 'node',
      className: 'HTMLButtonElement',
      description: 'button.paging-button',
      objectId: '144722812805955845.3.5'
    },
    _frame: Frame {
      _url: 'https://invawspivis01.dtinet.net/PIVision/#/Displays/3734/VIC%20-%20Site%20Update%20Dashboard',
      _detached: false,
      _loaderId: '9F2810160C0B1BFDD2882993D0524F3B',
      _lifecycleEvents: [Set],
      _frameManager: [FrameManager],
      _parentFrame: null,
      _id: '1B585848F903D3A22CDE31DD75022A81',
      _childFrames: Set(0) {},
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _mainWorld: [DOMWorld],
      _secondaryWorld: [DOMWorld],
      _name: undefined
    },
    _page: Page {
      eventsMap: Map(0) {},
      emitter: [Object],
      _closed: false,
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _pageBindings: Map(0) {},
      _javascriptEnabled: true,
      _workers: Map(0) {},
      _fileChooserInterceptors: Set(0) {},
      _userDragInterceptionEnabled: false,
      _handlerMap: [WeakMap],
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _target: [Target],
      _keyboard: [Keyboard],
      _mouse: [Mouse],
      _touchscreen: [Touchscreen],
      _accessibility: [Accessibility],
      _frameManager: [FrameManager],
      _emulationManager: [EmulationManager],
      _tracing: [Tracing],
      _coverage: [Coverage],
      _screenshotTaskQueue: [TaskQueue],
      _viewport: [Object]
    },
    _frameManager: FrameManager {
      eventsMap: [Map],
      emitter: [Object],
      _frames: [Map],
      _contextIdToContext: [Map],
      _isolatedWorlds: [Set],
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _page: [Page],
      _networkManager: [NetworkManager],
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _mainFrame: [Frame]
    }
  },
  ElementHandle {
    _disposed: false,
    _context: ExecutionContext {
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _world: [DOMWorld],
      _contextId: 3,
      _contextName: ''
    },
    _client: CDPSession {
      eventsMap: [Map],
      emitter: [Object],
      _callbacks: Map(0) {},
      _connection: [Connection],
      _targetType: 'page',
      _sessionId: '23E3541B1A29459485B04919F5C5C74A'
    },
    _remoteObject: {
      type: 'object',
      subtype: 'node',
      className: 'HTMLButtonElement',
      description: 'button.paging-button',
      objectId: '144722812805955845.3.6'
    },
    _frame: Frame {
      _url: 'https://invawspivis01.dtinet.net/PIVision/#/Displays/3734/VIC%20-%20Site%20Update%20Dashboard',
      _detached: false,
      _loaderId: '9F2810160C0B1BFDD2882993D0524F3B',
      _lifecycleEvents: [Set],
      _frameManager: [FrameManager],
      _parentFrame: null,
      _id: '1B585848F903D3A22CDE31DD75022A81',
      _childFrames: Set(0) {},
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _mainWorld: [DOMWorld],
      _secondaryWorld: [DOMWorld],
      _name: undefined
    },
    _page: Page {
      eventsMap: Map(0) {},
      emitter: [Object],
      _closed: false,
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _pageBindings: Map(0) {},
      _javascriptEnabled: true,
      _workers: Map(0) {},
      _fileChooserInterceptors: Set(0) {},
      _userDragInterceptionEnabled: false,
      _handlerMap: [WeakMap],
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _target: [Target],
      _keyboard: [Keyboard],
      _mouse: [Mouse],
      _touchscreen: [Touchscreen],
      _accessibility: [Accessibility],
      _frameManager: [FrameManager],
      _emulationManager: [EmulationManager],
      _tracing: [Tracing],
      _coverage: [Coverage],
      _screenshotTaskQueue: [TaskQueue],
      _viewport: [Object]
    },
    _frameManager: FrameManager {
      eventsMap: [Map],
      emitter: [Object],
      _frames: [Map],
      _contextIdToContext: [Map],
      _isolatedWorlds: [Set],
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _page: [Page],
      _networkManager: [NetworkManager],
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _mainFrame: [Frame]
    }
  }
]
```

As you can see I have what appear to be two elementHandles, but somehow `await page.$$(PAGING_BUTTON)[1]` returns undefined?

Comment: It appears that I have made a mistake, I am accessing `pagingButton[1]` which I'm expecting an element handle but is returning undefined. However `pagingButton.length` is 2

Comment: I also should mention that the elements I am trying to select are buttons that control a paginated list. I am trying to advance the list using the second button that matches this selector

Comment: Use parentheses to enforce order of ops: `(await page.$$(PAGING_BUTTON))[1]`